# Using CoilImage in Jetpack Compose, how can I remove the top and bottom padding after the image is downloaded

Tags: android, image, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I have a simple CoilImage implementation in my project where I download an image through an url, and then proceed to move the image state into an Image Composable. That's going smooth so far, but I'm facing a small problem where undesirable paddings are being added to the image. The image composable is inside a column with no fixed height. How can I get rid of these paddings while retaining the image dimension?

[image]

I've tried a couple of solutions such as using wrapContentHeight, putting it in a box and clipping it, using contentScale etc, but I just can't seem to get rid of the green spaces.

```
   @Composable
   fun HorizontalTextWithObject(enumerationItem: TextWithObjectPresentable) {
      Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f), 
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top) {
            Image(modifier = Modifier, enumerationItem)
        }
        Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(2f)) {
            Title(modifier = Modifier, enumerationItem)
            Description(enumerationItem)
        }
      }
    }


    @Composable
    fun Image(modifier: Modifier, 
    enumerationItem:TextWithObjectPresentable) {

    CoilImage(
    { request },
    success = { imageState ->
        imageState.imageBitmap?.let {
            val width = it.width.dp
            val height = ((width / 5) * 3)

            Image(bitmap = it, contentDescription = "",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(width)
                    .height(height)
                    .background(SDColor.green),
            )
        }
    },
)
}
```

I tried ContentScale.Crop but it is not what I'm looking for as it will just fill the paddings heightwise

[image]

Comment: The default [`contentScale`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/images/customize) is `ContentScale.Fit`. Did you try to use `ContentScale.Crop`

Comment: Agree with @GabrieleMariotti please add contentScale = ContentScale.Crop property to Image.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, I did try that but it being cropped is not what I'm looking for. It will just fill those paddings that I want to remove with the image. I want to retain the image as it is but those paddings being cropped away/removed

Comment: Can you post the full code : Image+Parent container ? Is the image smaller or bigger than the size of parent?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I have updated the code as requested

Comment: Which version of Coil are you using? CoilImage was deprecated many months ago.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I'm using landscapist
"com.github.skydoves:landscapist-coil:2.1.2"